# Advanced best practices for ASP.NET MVC2 & JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am going forward with developing my first ASP.NET MVC web app, coming from years of ASP.NET WebForm development. I have already read an MVC book so I know what MVC is all about. I like to use the latest and the greatest so I am planning to use VS 2010, MVC2, C#4 and jQuery 1.4.

Any best practices or design patterns when using ASP.NET MVC with JQuery?

Any very good web resources in this topic? Any good sample application which is using MVC2 & JQuery hand in hand (in CodePlex, Google Code or otherwise)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out this site http://www.mvc101.net/Articles/framework~MVC2/1

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Tailspin Travel](http://tailspintravel.codeplex.com/) sample application on codeplex.  It uses MVC2.  Another great source of jQuery and/or latest MVC news and articles is Elija Manor's [blog](http://feeds.feedburner.com/webdevnet).

Answer (score 0):

Not C# 4 but nerddinner.com

Comment: He can still get an idea of MVC at work since it is his first MVC enabled site.  As I mentioend it also isnt C# 4.0

Comment: I know but I have been specific. For example I want an application which uses strongly typed HTML helpers instead of the older style.